# Good book to learn Unix API?

Tags: unix

I would love to learn to program in pure UNIX with C kernell calls and all this, but I basically don't know where to start...

Books are usually the best way, so that's why I'm asking for one - but some good online material would be OK too. But please, no wikipedia - I don't want an encyclopedia, I want some book to guide me through unix APIs and show me what amazing can be done there (such like Aaron Hillegass and his Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X), not a book to throw random stuff at me.

ok, that's pretty much my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've got the book you are looking for: ["Advanced UNIX Programming"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131411543). There is another book, ["Advanced Programming in a Unix Environment"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131411543) that is quite good. I suggest the first to begin with.

Comment: The first book is by W. Richard Stevens and dates from the 90s but is a real classic.  Well worth reading.

Comment: The second is Stevens and Rago, and is similar but more recent. You want the second edition of that.

Comment: @cletus No, it's not. It's by Marc J Rochkind, and it's really a great book.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to "Advanced UNIX Programming" as pheze suggested, most UNIX system support the POSIX norm. For this you could begin with the [O'reilly book on POSIX](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780937175736/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

[The Art of Unix Programming](http://books.google.com/books?id=CZae0PbOXJMC&dq=the+art+of+unix+programing&printsec=frontcover&source=bn&hl=en&ei=1_GhSa-oO9KgtwfXpJiDDQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&resnum=4&ct=result#PPR10,M1) is a good one.